# how to input csv file into Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, prediction

I placed a prediction model code inside views.py of Django i need to pass input data from html page to views.py. How to feed csv file into Django views.py through html page.And that csv file further used for read with pandas to  proceed for my prediction model
in views.py

```
def read(request):
  f=request.FILES('filename')
  df=pd.read_csv('f')
```

page.html

```
<form action="{% url 'count' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/formdata">
   <input type = "file" name = "filename" />{% csrf_token%}

   <input type="submit" value="FORECAST"/>
```

it shows an error 'MultiValueDict' object is not callable

Comment: you need to be more specific, read [mcve].

Comment: This does not show any of your effort and likely that no one can answer properly. Add some of your code.

Comment: The code you have should work to upload the file, although you would need to pass the variable `f`, not the string `'f'`, to Pandas. Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: it shows an error 'MultiValueDict' object is not callable @DanielRoseman

Comment: Because FILES uses the dictionary syntax.

Comment: how to proceed with my code wt kind of manipulation should be taken ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the input field parameter in square bracket as dictionary needs square bracket.

```
f=request.FILES['filename']
```